# How to fix HTML position and scaling property?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my personal website, just learning. I have a large, main block of text with my site name, and under it some links to my social media, etc. The problem is the large, main block of text scales perfectly, but the small text under it does not.

The code I currently use for placing it (small text **AND** large, large is first in Qwigley font) is here:

```
<!--text-->
<div class="center">
<p style="position: absolute; top: 32%; left: 50%;  transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); font-family: 'Qwigley'; font-style: normal; font-
size: 72px; color: white; text-shadow:0px 0px 5px white;">ndb.life</p>
<a style="position: absolute; top: 44%; left: 44.5%;  transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); font-family: 'Courier New'; font-size: 14px; font-
style: normal; color: white; text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white; text-
decoration: none;" href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/xfh" rel="noopener
noreferrer" target="_blank">(main) steam</a>
<a style="position: absolute; top: 44%; left: 50%;  transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); font-family: 'Courier New'; font-size: 14px; font-
style: normal; color: white; text-shadow:0px 0px 1px white;">youtube</a>
<a style="position: absolute; top: 44%; left: 54%;  transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); font-family: 'Courier New'; font-size: 14px; font-
style: normal; color: white; text-shadow:0px 0px 1px white;">configs</a>
<a style="position: absolute; top: 44%; left: 57.5%;  transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); font-family: 'Courier New'; font-size: 14px; font-
style: normal; color: white; text-shadow:0px 0px 1px white;">email</a>
</div>
```

The class used on the div is in my style.css here:

```
#center {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

If you run the code, you can mess with your browser's size and will notice the text goes inside each other and move weirdly (don't scale properly).

Any way to fix this so it scales properly? (site and codepen example linked below)

[site](http://www.ndb.life) [WARNING: Has (loud) audio]

example here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jYZLWJ

Comment: for starters, take out the inline style and use classes on your paragraphs

Comment: I know it's ugly, I was more looking for a solution than criticism on the way the code looks, thanks anyways. As I said it's just for fun and I'm learning, I've made 3 different sites, and so far this is the best and I'm near perfecting it (in my eyes). I'll clean it up and repost if needed when I get home, won't take too long if necessary.

Comment: Ugly code means you will have less eyes on it. if you make a *proper* demo with separate HTML & CSS you are more likely to get an answer. If you are interested in learning... *take the advice you are given*

Comment: I don't see a problem with the codepen demo, it's supposed to just show how the main text (ndb.life) moves and scales perfectly while the text under it doesn't. I did mess up on the placement a bit, was in a rush. Regardless I'll clean it up but by then the thread will be lost and I'll have to wait another 3 days to make another :p.

Comment: When you put position absolute on everything it becomes really hard to control and maintain certain bounds of restriction. You should really look into using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). It allows you to center elements horizontally and vertically making this layout super simple. It would also be a lot less effort on your end and save you the headache of debugging this kind of stuff.

Comment: Developer mode in a browser may show you what is being applied to those elements. That and "define select boxes to have dotted red lines to see what they are doing" debugging may be your best friend.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, thats the kind of answer I was looking for, I'll give it a go.

Comment: I'll try that too @jdv

Comment: Ethan; re your audio. It's a ***BAD IDEA*** to have automatic audio on a site, for processing power on mobile devices to simple unexpected (negative) sensation for visitors. If someone is at work and clicks on your site, this can potentially be a problem, and they will not be too happy with you or with your site.   If you insist on having audio then you should have a couple (2) seconds at the start when it's quite but a clear indicator of **HOW TO TURN AUDIO OFF**, and then increase the volume *gradually* after that time. Always retain ability to mute the audio.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Martin. I'll add a pause/play button shortly as well as fade the audio in when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all those inline styles, absolute positioning and transforms for single elements (which cause your links to overlap in smaller screen sizes). Put the header and menu links into a wrapper, center them in there using `text-align: center` and apply absolute position and transform only on that one to center it as follows:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 100%;
}
.center_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
}
.x1, .x2 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.x1 {
  font-family: "Qwigley";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px white;
}
.x2 a:link,
.x2 a:visited {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center_wrap">
  <p class="x1">ndb.life</p>
  <p class="x2">
    <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/xfh" rel="noopener
noreferrer" target="_blank">(main) steam</a>
    <a href="#">youtube</a>
    <a href="#">configs</a>
    <a href="#">email</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using it and the font doesn't show up and positioning is wrong, what did I mess up on?

Comment: which font, which positioning?

Comment: The positioning of the div, paragraphs, etc. I think my stylesheet isn't working correctly because I manually added style inline to the ndb.life paragraph and it works fine :/.

All fonts ^

Comment: I have this at beginning of my index.html

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: If it helps Matthew's solution made the same problem occur.

Comment: I meant that you have to erase all the inline styles, i.e. only use the HTML code I provided, and put the CSS I provided into your "style.css" file

Comment: If you're still online, the position and font of everything doesn't work, no inline style or not. The only way I got it working was putting the style inline instead.

Comment: My fault, it seems my style.css wasn't updating on site, I forced a refresh with CTRL + SHIFT + R (Chrome OS) or CTRL + F5 (Windows), it forces grabbing right from the site. Thank you for helping it works perfect :).

Answer (score 2):

I rebuilt your codepen to use `flexbox` instead of absolute positioning.

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/GyQyQB).

Play around in it even if you don't decide to use it. It may prove as a learning tool for you to see how much easier the management can be if you use classes. Also don't be hesitant to add more `divs`. It is better to add to many and learn how to trim it down than to not add enough.

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I just recently learned about divs and before it I was just doing everything without them, I'm still not too good at using them thought. Thanks for the example!

Comment: Looks a bit confusing but I think I could put it to use, thanks again.

Comment: It does take a while to get used to but that is what you should be looking into. Also, don't be intimidated to use a framework. There are tons of them out there but in my opinion [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is the easiest to learn from and once you grasp the concept you will be able to do so much more.

Answer (score 1):

Whoosh, I was listening to peaceful music loudly and your site just simultaneously killed my ears/scared the me half to death. But besides that..:

They are getting layered on top of each other because you have them set absolutely by percentages. So a smaller area is a smaller distance between each other. And since its absolute, they aren't in the same flow together, so the percentage is from the edge of the div, not the link next to it.

You need to set the links to be `display:inline-block` with a left/right margin to keep proper spacing. That'd be your best bet since your div is already centered on the screen. Then you can put `text-align:center` on the div to align the contents within.

Comment: Haha, sorry about that, should've warned about the music, I'll try that quickly before trying out the flex box thing, thanks.